# I'm getting error while trying to synthesize voice in Google's text to speech API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I do not know why I get this error in response to the following code.

```
# imports
from google.cloud import texttospeech_v1beta1 as texttospeech

AUDIO_PROCESS_ROOT = 'path_audio'  
VEL_NORMAL = 1.0
KEY_API_ROOT = 'path_key'

# set credentials environment
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]=KEY_API_ROOT+"nome.json"

def TextToSpeech(text):

 client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
 input_text = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text=text)
 voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(language_code='en-US', name='en-US-Wavenet- B',ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.MALE)

 #speaking_rate --> responsavel pela taxa de velocidade no intervalo de [0.25 a 4.0], sendo 1.0 a velocidade normal padrão

 audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEnc oding.MP3, speaking_rate=VEL_NORMAL)
 response = client.synthesize_speech(input_text, voice,audio_config)

 with open(AUDIO_PROCESS_ROOT+'audio_normal.mp3', 'wb') as out:
     out.write(response.audio_content)

TextToSpeech("Hi, how are you")
```

Error:

> RetryError(u'Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while calling '

Comment: Please post the error as text instead of an image

Comment: Okay, I thought it would be better with the picture.

Comment: It is a good practice to post error as text so that other users can copy it. It also increases readability.

Comment: Very good, makes perfect sense, thank you!

Comment: Is there more to your exception? Seems like part is missing.

Comment: No, just that, the rest of the code does not interfere with the API, and the problem was during the response, I'm not sure about the problem it gave, but I think Google's cloud service was out

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the Text-To-Speech API for your project? Or if you're just running it locally, have you set application default credentials? It's possible that you doesn't have the correct permissions and the request to the Text-To-Speech API is timing out.

I was able to get this working on App Engine as follows:

In `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: python37
```

In `requirements.txt`:

```
flask
google-cloud-texttospeech
```

In `main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, Response
from google.cloud import texttospeech

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
    input_text = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text="Hi, what's up")

    voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
        language_code="en-US",
        ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.MALE,
    )

    audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3
    )

    response = client.synthesize_speech(input_text, voice, audio_config)
    return Response(response.audio_content, mimetype='audio/mp3')
```

Comment: Surprisingly, the API worked perfectly and I did not make any changes to the code.
Yes, the service is enabled and the credentials are set.

Comment: Can you include more code around how you're trying to use the API in your question?